# Flutter send voice clip

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there any option to send voice clip from flutter app to mobile number  (sim card ) ? Please help me to solve this problem?

Is Is there any packages to send voice clip from app to phone number. Android, Ios ,

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Twilio to send voice clip programmatically to simcard from your flutter app.